# How to show the value of the bigger amount

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to display the Posting key of the bigger amount (I used MAX command to get that).

On the image I attached, I need to group that records with the same value at the same time subtract the higher amount to the smaller amount but the conflict here is I need to show the posting_key of the higher amount.

[image: POSTING_KEY]

```
SELECT  PUBLICATION_CODE,
    RS_GL_ACCT_NO,
    ASSIGNMENT,
    TEXT,
    RRAC_TYPE,
    MAX(INV_TAX_AMT)-MIN(INV_TAX_AMT) AS INV_TAX_AMT,
    RS_AMOUNT,
    POSTING_KEY
FROM SAP_TABLE
GROUP BY PUBLICATION_CODE,
     RS_GL_ACCT_NO,
     ASSIGNMENT,
     TEXT,
     RRAC_TYPE,
     RS_AMOUNT,
     POSTING_KEY;
```

Comment: Simple query would be fine and write it in SP is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
select
    a.PUBLICATION_CODE,
    a.RS_GL_ACCT_NO,
    a.TEXT,
    a.RRAC_TYPE,
    a.INV_TAX_AMT-b.INV_TAX_AMT AS INV_TAX_AMT,
    a.RS_AMOUNT,
    c.POSTING_KEY
from sap_Table a
join sap_Table b on (a.RS_GL_ACCT_NO = b.RS_GL_ACCT_NO and b.INV_TAX_AMT < a.INV_TAX_AMT)
join (select RS_GL_ACCT_NO, max(posting_key) as posting_key from sap_Table) c on (a.RS_GL_ACCT_NO = b.RS_GL_ACCT_NO)
```

Let me know if anything fails :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use analytic functions `row_number()`, `min()` and `max()`:

```
select p_code, gl_code, text, type, tax_amt, invoice_amt, posting_key
  from (
    select row_number() over (partition by p_code, gl_code order by tax_amt desc) as rn, 
           max(tax_amt) over (partition by p_code, gl_code) 
           -  min(tax_amt) over (partition by p_code, gl_code) as tax_amt,
           p_code, gl_code, text, type, invoice_amt, posting_key
      from sap_table )
  where rn = 1
```

Test data and output:

```
create table sap_table (p_code varchar2(2), gl_code number(6), text varchar2(25), 
  type varchar2(20), tax_amt number(8, 2), invoice_amt number(6), posting_key number(6));
insert into sap_table values ('LH', 160069, 'Prepaid Charge-Out 0916', 
                              'Tax For Charge', .96, 0, 53);
insert into sap_table values ('LH', 160069, 'Prepaid Charge-Out 0916', 
                              'Tax For Charge', .5,  0, 54);

P_CODE GL_CODE TEXT                      TYPE               TAX_AMT INVOICE_AMT POSTING_KEY
------ ------- ------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
LH      160069 Prepaid Charge-Out 0916   Tax For Charge        0,46           0          53
```